# exponential equation different base and 2x

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am "absolute beginner" and I am working on this equation:

$$ \frac{1+5^{(2x+1)}}{4} = 5^x $$

It's all day that I am working on it but I don't seem to be able to find a solution.
This is my last test:

$$ 1/4 + 5^{2x} + 5/4 = 5^x $$

$$ 1 + 5^{2x} = 5^x $$

Wondering if it can be correct until now?
Here I am bit stuck.
I thought to use logaritms, but I can't find a nice solution.

Any hints appreciated, I would really like to learn it and not looking just for the solution.
(I am trying to read as much as I can similar answers).

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Set $\displaystyle3^x=a\implies3^{2x+1}=3(3^x)^2=3a^2$ to find $$1+3a^2=4a\iff3a^2-4a+1=0$$

$\implies a=1=3^0,\dfrac13=3^{-1}$

Now for $\displaystyle c\ne0,\pm1;$ $c^x=c^y\implies x=y$

Comment: sorry, I am not able to understand your answer :/

Answer (score 1):

> Wondering if it can be correct until now?

Well, no. Note that 
$$\frac{1+3^{2x+1}}{4}=\frac 14+\frac{3^{2x+1}}{4}=\frac 14+\frac{3}{4}\times 3^{2x}.$$
So, we have
$$\frac 14+\frac{3}{4}\times (3^x)^2=3^x$$
Then, set $t=3^x$ to get
$$\frac 14+\frac 34t^2=t$$
which should be easy to do with.

Comment: agh so the first error was just on the exponents of the fraction! That I've put a sum instead of multiplication right?

Comment: @jsabina: Yes, I guess so.